# 3D object from Blender to .glTF not showing. Why?

Tags: export, gltf

I’m trying to export my 3D model to a .glTF file but it does not work. When I am checking my model in glTF viewer.com it does not display anything. Also when I am opening a new Blender project and importing the .glTF file I just made and exported it does not even work. I tried with just a cube and that worked. But not with my 3D model I have made.
Is there a setting I am missing or someone that have a clue what I am doing wrong?

(using Blender 4.0)
This is how I do it. See image:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess we might have to look at the actual file to see what the problem is. Just having a quick glance at half the model in viewport does not give much information. Since it worked with the cube, you seem to be exporting correctly in general.

Comment: Check if you're using Blender modifiers or other features that aren't included in glTF. The glTF format supports a robust PBR material, but not general Blender material nodes.  glTF supports skinning and shape keys (morphing), but not general Blender modifiers. See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html

Comment: What is the file size of the object your exporting does the size seem too small for your mesh this can indicate that nothing is being exported? maybe a material transparency setting is being exported accidentally.

Comment: I tried to remove all the materials.  I also  tried  including  modifiers  and it  still does not work. Regarding the size, I do not think there is somthing wrong. I uploaded the file in the question if someone  could take a look at  it since I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Would be very  appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I try exporting your model, this appears in the console.

```
10:41:46 | INFO: Starting glTF 2.0 export
10:41:46 | WARNING: Mesh Pontum 3d viewer.733 is not valid, and may be exported wrongly
10:41:46 | INFO: Extracting primitive: Pontum 3d viewer.733
Error: Array length mismatch (expected 173211, got 173139)
10:41:46 | INFO: Primitives created: 0
10:41:46 | WARNING: Mesh 'Pontum 3d viewer.733' has no primitives and will be omitted.
10:41:46 | INFO: Finished glTF 2.0 export in 0.0600123405456543 s
```

I notice the model appearance also gets messed up.

[image]

If I then select the mesh and **toggle into and then back out of Edit mode**, the mesh appears to look correct again.

Now I try to export a second time, and it works.

```
10:53:14 | INFO: Starting glTF 2.0 export
10:53:14 | INFO: Extracting primitive: Pontum 3d viewer.733
10:53:14 | INFO: Primitives created: 1
10:53:14 | INFO: Finished glTF 2.0 export in 0.13958263397216797 s
```

Note that **both** the first failed export and the edit mode toggle are necessary to fix it.

I don't know how you got this invalid model, but if you can reproduce it, you can report it on Blender's bug tracker.

Comment: It worked! I tried what you did and all came out fine. i appreciate your taking the time!